# Spring Data Specification API - Unidirectional Join OneToMany

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, specifications, criteria-api

I have two entities, a `Dokument`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DOKUMENT")
public class Dokument {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    ...
}
```

and `BusinessList`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BUSINESS_LIST")
public class BusinessList{

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "BUSINESS_LIST_NUMBER", unique = true)
    @NotNull
    private String businessListNumber;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "BUSINESS_LIST_ID")
    private List<Dokument> dokuments = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
}
```

I would like to find all Dokuments by businessListNumber. I am trying to make a query using Specification API. The raw SQL-Query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM DOKUMENT d 
INNER JOIN BUSINESS_LIST b ON d.BUSINESS_LIST_ID = b.id  
WHERE b.BUSINESSLIST_NUMMER = :businessListNumber
```

However with Specification API it is not that straight forward. If I would have the bidirectional relation between those two the method would be very simple:

```
    public static Specification<Dokument> businessListNumberEqual(String businessListNumber) {
        return (Root<Dokument> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) -> {
            if (businessListNumber == null) {
                return null;
            }
            Join<Dokument, BusinessList> businessListJoin = root.join("businessList", JoinType.INNER);
            return builder.equal(businessListJoin .get("businessListNumber"), businessListNumber);
        };
    }
```

Unfortunately, I am not allowed to use bidirectional relation here and I have failed to try to build this.

Could you help me? :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead creating one specification try creating 2 different specification one for join and 2nd one for where clause.

Use BusinessList repository you should get your expected query

```
public static Specification<BusinessList> joinDocument() {
    return (root, query, builder) -> {           
        root.join("dokuments", JoinType.INNER);
        return null;
    };
}
    
public static Specification<BusinessList> businessListNumberEqual(String businessListNumber) {
    return (root, query, builder) -> {
        if (businessListNumber == null) {
            return null;
        }            
        return builder.equal(root.get("businessListNumber"), businessListNumber);
    };
}

 Specification.where(joinDocument()).and(businessListNumberEqual("businessListNumber"));
```

Check out the code on git https://github.com/chetanchilhate/Spring-Data-Jpa-Specification-Join

Comment: Hey Chetan, many thanks for you answer! Unfortunately I think it does not solve the puzzle, as I need to return Specification<Dokument>. The background for this is that I have huge specification query for my GUI search mask. Afterwards, when the Specifications are built I am using a dokumentDao.findAll(specifications). Therefore I cannot pass the Specification<BusinessList> there :(